# Display greek letters in jasperreports with JrxmlDatasource

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports

I am trying to display greek letters in PDF generated by jasperreport. First I create XML, then xml datasource and pass it to jaspper. 
XML:

```
     Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
   ....
   Element analysisElement = doc.createElement("Analysis");

   //text value is from the database 
   Text analysisText = doc.createTextNode(anayisisObject.getName());
   analysisElement.appendChild(analysisText);
```

Datasource:

```
JRXmlDataSource xmlDataSource = new JRXmlDataSource(doc,"/ReportFailedAnalysis");
```

JRXML textField:

```
 <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
   <reportElement style="obicni" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="203" height="12"/>
     <textElement markup="styled">
        <font fontName="Arial" size="9" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
     </textElement>
     <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{Analysis}]]>  
     </textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

Database encoding is Cp1250 if that is important and greek letters are saved as html encoding for example &#x393;. If I just pass that value, xml probably alter & to &amp, and i get Γ in my pdf. 
If I replace it with utf character \u03C6, I get "?" in my PDF.
I know there is a way to display that field becaise when I export XML to file, change character from &amp;#x393; back to &#x393; , import it as a datasource in iReport, I get the letter I wantad.

Comment: I have discovered that when I view it in iReport viewer it is ok, but when I save it as PDF, character is lost. When I open it with Adobe reader i get "?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reasearch I have discovered that PDF fonts are the cause of the problem. I have been using version 3.6, so i switched to version 3.7, to be able to embed fonts in PDF and used the method described on the blog: 
[Link.](http://javaskeleton.blogspot.com/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html)
I have used solution number 2(the easy way), but be sure to check solution number 1 in order to chose right fonts for bold, italic etc. Arial font was quite enough for me.